# Get count minimum

Tags: sql

I have four table:

```
 - PLAYER (Name, City, TotWonTornaments)
 - TOURNAMENT (IdTournament, Date, Winner)
 - ATTENDEES (IdTournament, PlayerName, TotalScore)
 - GAME (IdTournament, PlayerName1, PlayerName2, ScorePlayer1, ScorePlayer2, LastGame)
```

I want to write a query to find the player who got number of times the worst score in different tournament.
this is the query I have wirten

```
select PlayerName , min(TotalScore)  from ATTENDEES A join TOURNOMANT T where A.idTournament = T.idTournament group by A.idTournament
```

untill now I can recognize for each tounament who got minium score but I do not know how to get count who got most time min score??

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is a high score good or a low score good (golf vs badminton, say)?  It affects the interpretation of 'worst', though the title contains 'minimum', suggesting it is more like badminton than golf.

Comment: I'm having difficulty interpreting your requirement to "find the player who got number of times the worst score in different tournament", even with the clarification after the outline query. Suppose player 'Lose A. Lot' scored 0 points in each of 10 games in 4 different tournaments, and (assuming 0 is bad), no other player did worse than that.  Which number are you after?  0 or 10 or 4 or something else?

Comment: Further, suppose player 'Wins A. Few-Times' scored 1 point 12 times in 5 tournaments (and 'Lose A. Lot' didn't play in any of those tournaments) — are you after this player instead of 'Lose A. Lot'?

Comment: I think the OP is talking how to get the minimum count like MIN(COUNT(part))

in a table that has multiple duplicated values

If the person has scored low than 5 then add it to the count.
Then the person scored less than 5 a couple times then add it to the count.

Maybe the goal is to get the player who scores less the most.